# Junit :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I am trying to run a Junit test to test a service layer. I am using Spring 4, hibernate 5.2.3 and JUnit 4.12. I don't know why i am getting this exception while running the test code.I tried all the possible ways to execute the code but i got failed to run test cases.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjecti...
 ...
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
LocalSessionFactoryBean.isSingleton()
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127)....
...
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
LocalSessionFactoryBean.isSingleton()
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5f2c3f95.getObject(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 38 more
```

The test class is as below-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
public class TestClass{

    @Test
    public void testGetAge() {

        int age = HelperClass.getAge(Utiity.getCurrentDate());
        assertEquals(0, age);               

    }
}
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
>           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
>           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
>           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>           xsi:schemaLocation="            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
> 
>   <context:property-placeholder location="/spring.properties" />
>       <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">        <constructor-arg index="0"
> value="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" />
>   </bean>         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.easymock.EasyMock"
> factory-method="createMock">      <constructor-arg index="0"
> value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />
>   </bean>
```

Comment: It can't create `bean with name 'sessionFactory':`. Try to mock it. Also, post your `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Please check the applicationcontext xml

Comment: Check the path of the file `applicationcontext.xml`.

Comment: path of applicationcontext.xml -\src\test\resources and path of test class is \src\test\java\package

Comment: Try `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})`.

Comment: it's giving the same error :(

Comment: Why are you mocking the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`? Generally when doing things like that you are on the wrong path.